# How to track changes not only in the source table but also tables that are joined to it?

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

Assume I have this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE 
select A.code,B.name,C.add
from codes A
left join names B on A.fid=B.id
left join addresses C on B.num=C.id
where A.datechanged>somedate;
```

This adds new records for every row in A that gets modified. I want it to also track changes in B and C, so for example if B.datechanged>somedate is true but A.datechanged>somedate is false, a new row still gets added.

In other words, I want it to pull data from all three tables if datechanged>somedate any of the tables, not just A. How can i do this? I contemplated repeating the same statement with different tables in the FROM clause but I have about 10 tables that are being joined. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Trigger on each table which calls a procedure to insert records in all 3 "journal" tables.

Comment: Are you building source control? - there are free tools out there

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you just want multiple conditions with an `OR`, i.e. `where a.datechanged > somedate OR b.datechanged > somedate OR c.datechanged > somedate`.

Comment: No, I'm doing ETL for a data warehouse. @xQbert Do you mean a trigger on update in A,B,C to join the remaining tables and insert a new record in MYTABLE? I'd rather avoid triggers if possible and  that seems like just another way of repeating the same code for each table..unless I'm misunderstanding you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want multiple predicates combined with an `OR` clause

```
WHERE a.datechanged > somedate
   OR b.datechanged > somedate
   OR c.datechanged > somedate
```

A SQL statement specifies particular set to be returned.  Predicates are combined using standard boolean algebra to determine which rows are returned.  In this case, if any of the predicates are satisfied, the row will be returned.  Obviously, if you used `AND` to combine the predicates, then you would only get rows that satisfy all three conditions.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed something so basic. Need some afternoon coffee now!